# Prevent Visual Studio C++ from merging identical functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

In order to get the length of functions, I'm using empty functions to mark where each function ends, like so:

```
void f()
{
    printf("ooga\n");
}
__declspec(noinline, naked) void f_end() { __asm { nop } };
```

To get the length of f, I just subtract f_end - f, decrementing for any INT3 used as padding.

But if I add another function:

```
void g()
{
    printf("booga\n");
}
__declspec(noinline, naked) void g_end() { __asm { nop } };
```

the f_end() and g_end() appears to be merged into one single function (verified by looking at the disassembly in OllyDbg). If I make each function unique it won't happen, but I'll be needing a ton of these.

Is there any optimization switch I can flick to prevent this from happening?

I've skimmed through the settings available in the Visual Studio menus (had to set /OPT:NOREF in order for the f_end and g_end to not be skipped altogether) and tried optimize("", off) to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  AFAICS, this is going to be brittle for a number of reasons.

Comment: This is an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).  You may want to edit your question to ask how to get the length of functions.  That's what you're really trying to figure out, it seems.

Comment: you're also ignoring the padding...

Comment: You're also ignoring code motion due to PGO. Why do you need the function length anyway? I hope you aren't trying to inject code.

Comment: @Drew Dormann I wanted to know the answer to this question. Another situation where I've been looking for this is when you have a bunch of miniscule (identical) stubs that need to be patched in run time.

Comment: @V-X "decrementing for any INT3 used as padding" I don't need it to be valid for every situation, just when -I- am compiling it

Comment: @Raymond Chen How so? 

(ugh, I want to quote multiple people in the same comment)

Comment: this is just an invalid idea. There is no general method of detection of function size... in high level language you don't have any control of function placing and size...

Comment: "this is just an invalid idea. There is no general method of detection of function size"
Hence I'm using a hack. And like I said: it works for me and I don't care about the rest. The question is not "how to get the function length" but rather "Prevent Visual Studio C++ from merging identical functions" (to which Mike Vine gave the correct solution, and mah provided an alternative approach for my particular case). If you want to debate the former there are plenty of questions on that subject

Comment: There is no requirement that the bytes for a function be contiguous. Optimizers can put frequently executed code in one location and rarely executed code in another. There is also no requirement that f_end come immediately after f. The optimizer might move all the stub functions to their own page. To force function ordering use the /Order option. I don't know what /Order does if the function is discontiguous. Also, f might be auto-inlined by the optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[/OPT:NOICF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is probably the setting you're looking for. It tells the compiler to not fold (merge) identical comdats.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to make things a little easier, without worrying about the compiler:

```
#define FUNC_END(funcname)                             \
__declspec(noinline, naked) void funcname ## _end () { \
    funcname ## _end();                                \
}
```